# Passing filename as parameter to fopen() is not working

Tags: c, file, fopen

I am trying to read my filename from an .ini file and then pass it to fopen de actually writing in it. But it's not working. It's a problem with the value of the file name. Here is my code:

```
FILE * ini_file = fopen("testc.ini", "r");
char *in = NULL;
char *out = NULL;
char *p;
const int bufferLength = 255;
char buffer[bufferLength];

while (fgets(buffer, bufferLength, ini_file)) {
    p = strtok(buffer, "[]=");
    if (strcmp("in", p)==0) {
        p = strtok(NULL, "[]=");
        in = (char*)malloc((strlen(p) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(in, p);
    }
    else if (strcmp("out", p) == 0) {
        p = strtok(NULL, "[]=");
        out = (char*)malloc((strlen(p) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(out, p);
    }
}
fclose(ini_file);
FILE *f_in = fopen(in, "wb+");
if (f_in == NULL) {
    return;
}
fwrite(&p1, sizeof(p1), 1, f_in);
fclose(f_in);
```

Comment: Does the return value of `fopen` provide any useful information? (BTW, `const` variables don't count as constant expressions so I think you've unnecessarily made `buffer` a VLA)

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of `in` before using it in fopen

Comment: Yes, if I print the value of in it works

Comment: But if I use it in fopen function and comment the if, I have exception

Comment: Thanks a lot @user3121023. You have solved my problem